# Javascript: Go over an array of objects and add a key/value according to whether one of the values is included in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Basically, here is what I am trying to do.

1. Go through each entry of the 'food' array and check whether the 'category' value is included in the 'target' array.
2. Insert another key/value pair (target:true or target:false) accordingly.

i.e.,

```
const food = [
   {category: 'fruit', price: 5}, 
   {category: 'meat', price: 10}, 
   {category: 'drink', price: 3}
];

const target = ['fruit', 'meat'];

const result = [
   {category: 'fruit', price: 5, target: true}, 
   {category: 'meat', price: 10, target: true}, 
   {category: 'drink', price: 3, target: false}
];
```

What will be the code to do this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const food = [
    { category: "fruit", price: 5 },
    { category: "meat", price: 10 },
    { category: "drink", price: 3 },
];
const target = ["fruit", "meat"];

const result = food.map(f => ({ ...f, target: target.includes(f.category) }));

console.log(result);
```